# Difference between std::search and std::find_first_of

Tags: c++, find, std

I am trying to grasp the difference between `std::search` and `std::find_first_of`

They have the same prototypes:

```
template <class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
   ForwardIterator1 find_first_of (ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                                   ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2);

template <class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2, class BinaryPredicate>
   ForwardIterator1 find_first_of (ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                                   ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2,
                                   BinaryPredicate pred);

template <class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
   ForwardIterator1 search (ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                            ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2);

template <class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2, class BinaryPredicate>
   ForwardIterator1 search (ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                            ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2,
                            BinaryPredicate pred);
```

They both return the same thing: An iterator to the first occurrence of the sequence [first2, last2) inside [first1, last1). (using equality, or a binary predicate)

So what is the difference ? Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is that `std::search` searches for a *whole range* of elements within another range, while `std::find_first_of` searches for a *single* element from a range within another range.

Answer (score 12):

`std::find_first_of` is looking for any of the elements in your search range. It will return an iterator to the first occurrence of any of the elements in `[s_first1, s_first2]`.

`std::search` is looking for the whole sequence you passed. Such, it will return an iterator to the first occurrence of the sequence `[s_first1, s_first2]`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A{1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5};
    std::vector<int> search_range{2, 4, 6};
    std::vector<int> find_first_of_range{6, 5};

    auto it_search = std::search(A.begin(), A.end(),
        search_range.begin(), search_range.end());
    std::cout << std::distance(A.begin(), it_search) << std::endl; // 3

    auto it_find_first_of = std::find_first_of(A.begin(), A.end(),
        find_first_of_range.begin(), find_first_of_range.end());
    std::cout << std::distance(A.begin(), it_find_first_of) << std::endl; // 5
}
```

[Runnable on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c82da0092ff81e2)

Answer (score 5):

`std::search()` finds where the range of elements that matches the entire sequence of `[first2..last2)` is, while `find_first_of()` finds the first single element that matches one of the elements in `[first2..last2)`.