# How to find a vector inside a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, search, vector

I am trying to write a program that has to search presence of a vector inside a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>  
#include <string>

struct B
{
    std::vector<int> a;
};

struct A
{
    std::vector<B> a;
    int x;
    std::string n;
};

int main()
{
    A s;
    B b1,b2, b3;
    b1.a.push_back(10);
    b1.a.push_back(29);
    b2.a.push_back(50);
    b2.a.push_back(69);
    s.a.push_back(b1);
    s.a.push_back(b2);
    std::vector<int> a22;
    b3.a.push_back(10);
    b3.a.push_back(29);
    auto it = std::search(s.a.begin(), s.a.end(), b3.a.begin(), b3.a.end());
    if (it != s.a.end())
        std::cout << "Element found in vector\n";
    else
       std::cout << "Element not found in vector\n";
   return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the code I get lots of error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 try66.cpp
In file included from C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from try66.cpp:1:
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equal_to_iter::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) const [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<B*, std::vector<B> >; _Iterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]':
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:237:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator1 std::__search(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2, _ForwardIterator2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _ForwardIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<B*, std::vector<B> >; _ForwardIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _BinaryPredicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equal_to_iter]'
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4023:47:   required from '_FIter1 std::search(_FIter1, _FIter1, _FIter2, _FIter2) [with _FIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<B*, std::vector<B> >; _FIter2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]'
try66.cpp:31:71:   required from here
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:86:23: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'B' and 'int')
       { return *__it1 == *__it2; }
                   ^
```

I am not sure what helper function we need to create to resolve the issue?

Comment: You are looking for `ints` in a vector of `Bs`.

Comment: Thanks - how can I search a vector of int from A's struct vector 'a' having B's vector of int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, "you are looking for `int`s in a vector of `B`s".

Edit: From your comments, I understand you want to use [`std::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/), and not the search method. Read more in [Difference between std::search and std::find_first_of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017338/difference-between-stdsearch-and-stdfind-first-of).

You have to provide your own predicate to [`std::search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/), in order to help with the comparison, like this for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>  
#include <string>

struct B
{
    std::vector<int> a;
};

struct A
{
    std::vector<B> a;
    int x;
    std::string n;
};

bool mypredicate (B b, int value) {
    return std::find(b.a.begin(), b.a.end(), value) != b.a.end();
}


int main()
{
    A s;
    B b1,b2, b3;
    b1.a.push_back(10);
    b1.a.push_back(29);
    b2.a.push_back(50);
    b2.a.push_back(69);
    s.a.push_back(b1);
    s.a.push_back(b2);
    std::vector<int> a22;
    b3.a.push_back(10);
    b3.a.push_back(29);
    auto it = std::find_first_of(s.a.begin(), s.a.end(), b3.a.begin(), b3.a.end(), mypredicate);
    if (it != s.a.end())
        std::cout << "Element found in vector\n";
    else
       std::cout << "Element not found in vector\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Element found in vector

Comment: Thanks I get the idea but output of the code is that Element not found in vector - mypredicate does it needs to add some extra validation?

Comment: You can simplify mypredicate to return std::find(b.a.begin(), b.a.end(), value) != b.a.end();

Comment: Thanks - but the search for the vector is failing always even though we ensure that the search vector is present

Comment: It seems that mypredicate is being called thrice with values 10,29 and 10 and then fails

Comment: @Caleth yes, I was going to do that, but I was working on the edit based on Programmer's comments. Thanks though! Programmer, please read my edit, I think you are using the wrong method.

Comment: Thanks  for the details and example provided - it gives me in-depth idea of how to implement and new learnings